# Invalid Left Side Assignment

Tags: javascript

line 1 :

```
var span = document.getElementById("spanPBBestEst" + rowNum);
```

line 2 :

```
span.innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("formFLEDetail.frmRepEst" + rowNum).value) + parseInt(document.getElementsByName("formFLEDetail.frmClubEst" = rowNum).value);
```

I get ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in line 2

Comment: "formFLEDetail.frmClubEst" = rowNum <-- You fat fingered it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fat fingered your string concatenation.

```
span.innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("formFLEDetail.frmRepEst" + rowNum).value) + 
parseInt(document.getElementsByName("formFLEDetail.frmClubEst" = rowNum).value);
                                                              ^^^
```

The equal needs to be a plus...BUT once you fix that, you have another error. `getElementsByName` returns a collection and you act like it returns one value. You need to reference the index you want to read the value of.

```
parseInt(document.getElementsByName("formFLEDetail.frmClubEst" + rowNum)[0].value)
                                                              ^^        ^^^
```